# Using Requests to get specific JSON API information in Python

Tags: json, python-3.x, python-requests

I'm using Requests in Pyhton 3.6.2 to pull Json data from a url, however i cannot for the life of me figure out how to pull a specific data point. This is one of many attempts i've tried. I'm no pro at python and am learning as i go.

This is the api url https://zkillboard.com/api/losses/corporation/98459043/limit/1/ which shows the latest loss in a game. Documentation for that API [can be found here](https://github.com/zKillboard/zKillboard/wiki/API-(Killmails)). Specifically i'm trying to pull the KillID info which can vary depending on the loss.

```
"killID": 64401412,
```

My code:

```
import requests
import json
url = requests.get('https://zkillboard.com/api/json/corporation/98459043/losses/limit/1/')
data = json.loads(url.text)

print (data)
```

returns [{'killID': 64401412, 'solarSystemID': 30045352, [..]

```
print (data[0])
```

returns {'killID': 64401412, 'solarSystemID': 30045352, [..]

```
print (data[0]['KillID'])
```

returns "KeyError: 'KillID'"

```
print (data['KillID'])
```

returns "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str"

From what i've managed to find out from other peoples questions, requests is returning the json data as a list not dict. Any help would be much appreciated on what will likely be a very simple solution.

Comment: It's a lowercase `k`, not `K`. Use `data[0]['killID']`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're nearly there! The request is returning a list of dicts, so your `data[0]['dictkey']` format is correct. However, remember that Python is case sensitive. It looks like the key you want is `killID` (lower k) but you're trying `KillID` (upper K).

Try `data[0][killID]`

Comment: Haha wow thank you! I knew it would be something stupid like that.